# How to process an array of XML tag to get each object using Python?

Tags: python, xml, loops, multidimensional-array, extract

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country>
     <number no="2008" info="update">
          <string name="ruth" code="XX1" />
          <string name="amy" code="XX2" />
          <string name="lisa" code="XX3" />
          <string name="graham" code="XX4" />
          <!-- Working -->
          <detail name="man1" class="A1">
               <string name="ruth" code="1AV1"/>
               <string name="amy" code="1AV2"/>
          </detail>
          <detail name="man2" class="A2">
               <string name="lisa" code="2AV1"/>
               <string name="graham" code="2AV2"/>
          </detail>
     </number>
     <number no="2006" info="update">
          <string name="grace" code="XX5" />
          <string name="emy" code="XX6" />
          <string name="toms" code="XX7" />
          <!-- Working -->
          <detail name="woman1" class="B1">
               <string name="grace" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="woman2" class="B2">
               <string name="emy" code="2BV1"/>
               <string name="toms" />
          </detail>
     </number>
</Country>
```

I would like to get the value of a tag name and code by mapping the name size.

Here what I tried, but not finished and stuck on it.

```
ReadFile = ET.parse('test.xml')
codestring = 'B2'
nostring = '2008'
Name = ([nm.get("name")
               for nm in ReadFile.findall('.//detail[@class="{}"]/'.format(codestring))])
Code = ([cd.get("code")
               for cd in ReadFile.findall('.//detail[@class="{}"]/'.format(codestring))])

if len(Name) > 1 :
    message = "Name More Than One"
    if len(Code) < 1 :
        message = "code not specified"
        # I need to get the
        # get one of the code from here <string name="toms" code="XX7" />
        result = ["emy\2BV1" , "toms\XX7"] # this is my expected result. Im going to use each array to mapping a path in other process
elif len(Name) == 1 :
    message = "Name Is One"
else:
    message = "Name Not Found"
```

Anyway, I've done this process before with powershell. I did it like this.

```
if (($DriverFileName).Count -gt 1)
{
     $Message = "Name More Than One"
     $maxLoop = [math]::Min($DriverFileName.Count, $DriverFileVersion.Count)

     for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxLoop; $i++) {

          if (($DriverFileVersion[$i]).Count -lt 1)
          {
               $Message = "Version Not Specifiy"
               $DriverFileNameDefault = $DriverFileName[$i]
               $Default = (Select-Xml -Xml $ReadDriverXML -XPath "//family[@code='$DriverFamilyCode']/driver[@name='$DriverFileNameDefault']").Node.version
               $Path = '{0}\{1}' -f $DriverFileName[$i], $Default
          }
          elseif (($DriverFileVersion[$i]).Count -ge 1)
          {
               $Message = "Version Specified"
               $Path = '{0}\{1}' -f $DriverFileName[$i], $DriverFileVersion[$i]
          }
          else {

               if (Test-Path $DriversPath\$DriverFileVersion[$i]\*)
               {
                    $Message = "Version Can Not Query"
                    $Path = "$DriverFileName\*"
               }
               else {

                    $Message = "Version Unreachable"
               }
          }
          
          $InfFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $DriversPath\$Path\*.inf
     }
}
```

Anyone can help me to give advice and help really appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: what is 'name size'?

Comment: @balderman the name size that I mentioned above  mean the length of  here `if len(Name) > 1 :`

Comment: can you please share the desired output based on the given xml?

Comment: @balderman my expectation output is I need to use the value of tag XML as a string to mapping a path. For the example I used this value `<string name="emy" code="2BV1"/>` name and code to mapping the path like `emy/2BV1` but I need to consider the XML whether the length of the name and code are the same

Comment: you start by looking at `detail` and take the `name` and `code` but later on you mention  toms and emy. I dont understand how the 2 are related?

Comment: @balderman `emy` supposed to have `code=2BV1` and `toms` does not has code. So I need to find the code for `toms` from here `<string name="toms" code="XX7" />` by mapping with this attribute `number no="2006"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229757/discussion-between-cheries-and-balderman).